# How to listen for regular keys and key combinations in Python

Tags: python, input, keyboard

I want to make a program that will print out key combinations and regular keys. For example, if the user types `a`, I want the console to print `'a'` and if the user clicks on `shift + a` the console will print `'shift + a'`.

What library/code should I use? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: maybe try `pynput`

Comment: What exactly what I do to capture a keystroke such as 'shift + a'? Whenever an irregular key is pressed along with an alphabetical letter, a code is printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sort of rewrite the `pynput` sample code so that the program can monitor combination of `shift` key.

I made a global variable `SHIFT_STATE` to record if the `shift` key is pressed, and I believe you can expand this to monitor `ctrl`, `alt`, `cmd` keys and make the code looks prettier.

By the way, the library has the power to monitor global-hotkeys
however I did not look into it too much. You can check it out here: https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#global-hotkeys

```
from pynput import keyboard

SHIFT_STATE = False
def on_press(key):
    global SHIFT_STATE
    if key == keyboard.Key.shift:
        SHIFT_STATE = True
    else:
        try:
            if SHIFT_STATE:
                print(f'shift + {key}')
            else:
                print(key)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

def on_release(key):
    global SHIFT_STATE
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False
    elif key == keyboard.Key.shift:
        SHIFT_STATE = False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

and here's the screenshot I ran the code FYI
[image: pynput rewrite]